# Alfresco REST Api add Task

Tags: rest, api, alfresco

I am developing a java web application  to manage Alfresco users and tasks (create  and assign tasks to users ..)  using rest api , i couldn't add tasks with POST method as shown in this picture : 
[image]

Can anyone please suggest how  to handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Akah said, it's not the right service, also, you can find all deployed services in your Alfresco instance with there descriptions on http://localhost:8081/alfresco/service/index/all

Comment: can i add a service that allows me to start a process or a task ?

Comment: Yes, you can add your own service, this is an extention that contains a webscript to start workflows  https://github.com/owerfelli/start-workflow-extention

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the right method, this url only accepts GET.

You can use all theses methods : https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#/tasks, but I don't see one permitting to create a task.
I think this is because creating a task is not logic.

Maybe what you want to do is to create a process : https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/processes/createProcess

If you don't find what you need, you still have the option to create your own webscript https://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/tasks/ws-tutorials.html.